# Como ordenar (rapidamente) uma tabela do HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, tabela-html

Estou criando uma ferramenta para visualizar dados de importação e exportação dispondo-os em uma tabela, que pode acabar com milhares de linhas. Aqui vai um pequeno trecho para mostrar como ela está organizada:

```
<tr id="search-results-table-headerrow">
    <th id="th-mes">Mês</th>
    <th>Categoria</th>
    <th>País</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Meio de transporte</th>
    <th>Volume</th>
    <th>Peso bruto</th>
    <th>Valor financeiro</th>
</tr>
<tr class="innerRow">
    <td>Dezembro</td>
    <td>Produtos hortículas, plantas, raízes e tubérculos, comestíveis</td>
    <td>Turquia</td>
    <td>RS</td>
    <td>Marítima</td>
    <td>0.005</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

Pondo em palavras, cada entrada da tabela tem os campos mês, categoria, país, estado, meio de transporte, volume, peso bruto e valor financeiro. Eu gostaria de oferecer ao usuário a opção de ordenar a tabela por qualquer um destes atributos.

O `id` da minha tabela é `search-results-table`. A primeira coisa que eu tentei fazer foi obter a lista de linhas dessa tabela (`document.getElementById('search-results-table').rows`, converter isto para um `Array`, ordenar e atribuir a versão ordenada à tabela. Eu consegui fazer o ordenamento corretamente, mas a tabela simplesmente não atualizou. Isso que eu tentei fazer deveria funcionar ou eu posso ter cometido algum equívoco em alguma parte? Há algum "segredo" para atribuir uma lista de elementos para dentro de outro? (Infelizmente eu apaguei o código que eu tinha criado originalmente, mas era basicamente `document.getElementById('search-results-table').rows = arrayOrdenadoDeLinhas`).

Outra maneira que eu testei foi [essa proposta pela W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp). Pelo que eu entendi, ela faz algo como um *bubble sort* com as linhas da tabela. Eu só adaptei ela para a minha realidade e, de fato, funcionou. O problema é que ficou muito lento! Ordenar uma tabela de mil linhas demorou algo como uns quatro ou cinco minutos, e durante todo esse intervalo a página esteve congelada e irresponsiva. Logo, essa abordagem está fora de questão.

Apenas a título de contexto, este projeto na verdade não é web, é Python usando HTML + CSS + JS como front-end, via biblioteca [eel](https://github.com/ChrisKnott/Eel). Isso não influencia no que estamos discutindo aqui no tópico, no entanto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sobre o título da pergunta "rapidamente" depende do tamanho da tabela, é preciso testar. Há a possibilidade de order em outro elemento e depois substituir no HTML, usar diferentes algorítimos ou apenas mover os elementos (`append`), para isso precisa ter o tamanho real da tabela.

Quanto à pergunta, uma parte que não é possível responder sem ver o código é *"Eu consegui fazer o ordenamento corretamente, mas a tabela simplesmente não atualizou"*. Para responder isso, só vendo o código.

Vou demonstrar aqui um código básico, a partir da ideia da sua pergunta, onde afirmou que já obteve um array com os dados e ordenou (aqui usei o [array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) para fazer isso). Aqui, para deixar mais flexível, criei duas variáveis:

- `asc`: um boolean se é ordem ascendente ou não;
- `index`: o índice da coluna pela qual quer ordenar (começa por zero);

Para comparar os valores na ordenação, usei o [`localCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), e ao final `appendChild` para "mover" os itens ordenados, ou seja, tudo em puro `Javascript`:

```js
const asc = true;  // ordem: ascendente ou descendente
const index = 7;    // coluna pela qual se quer ordenar
const tabela = document.getElementById('search-results-table');

const arr = Array.from(tabela.querySelectorAll('tbody tr'));
const th_elem = tabela.querySelectorAll('th');

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  const a_val = a.children[index].innerText
  const b_val = b.children[index].innerText
  return (asc) ? a_val.localeCompare(b_val) : b_val.localeCompare(a_val)
})
arr.forEach(elem => {
  tabela.appendChild(elem)
});
```

```html
<table id="search-results-table" border="1">
   <thead>
     <tr id="search-results-table-headerrow">
        <th id="th-mes">Mês</th>
        <th>Categoria</th>
        <th>País</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Meio de transporte</th>
        <th>Volume</th>
        <th>Peso bruto</th>
        <th>Valor financeiro</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="innerRow">
        <td>Dezembro</td>
        <td>Produtos hortículas, plantas, raízes e tubérculos, comestíveis</td>
        <td>Turquia</td>
        <td>RS</td>
        <td>Marítima</td>
        <td>0.005</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="innerRow">
        <td>Janeiro</td>
        <td>Produtos hortículas, plantas, raízes e tubérculos, comestíveis</td>
        <td>Egito</td>
        <td>RS</td>
        <td>Marítima</td>
        <td>0.003</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="innerRow">
        <td>Fevereiro</td>
        <td>Produtos hortículas, plantas, raízes e tubérculos, comestíveis</td>
        <td>Marrocos</td>
        <td>RS</td>
        <td>Marítima</td>
        <td>0.002</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Notas: pode mudar os valores de `asc` e `index` a vontade pra adaptar a sua necessidade. Para fazer uma comparação mais complexa (duas colunas por exemplo) mude a lógica com o `localCompare`, pode combinar condições usando os operadores lógicos `||` e `&&`

Answer (score 1):

Vim apenas acrescentar duas soluções (no caso de interessar a alguém) que acabei encontrando, além da que o colega já ofereceu.

A primeira, e mais fácil de todas, eu encontrei [aqui (SO gringa)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55730907/13143292). Basta importar o este arquivo:

```
<script src="https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
```

No HTML e associar a tabela à classe `sortable`. Depois disso, basta clicar na coluna a ser ordenada no próprio cabeçalho e ele já ordena automaticamente. Como algumas das minhas colunas têm números, quero que eles sejam ordenados de acordo com sua magnitude, e não com seu valor lexicográfico. Não sei se tem como configurar para isso funcionar usando esse módulo (é um módulo?), teria que investigar mais a fundo. Ah, para funcionar, todas as linhas precisam estar dentro do `tbody`.

A outra técnica fui eu que fiz; é mais ou menos parecida com o que o @Ricardo Pontual postou:

```
var index; // o trecho que determina o index foi omitido por legibilidade  
sorting = function(a, b) {
        return a.children[index].innerText > b.children[index].innerText ? 1 : -1;
}

var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.innerRow');
var arrayOfSortedRows = Array.from(rows).sort(sorting);

for (let row of rows)
    row.remove();

// o usuário deseja ver em ordem decrescente
if (att.endsWith('-r'))
    arrayOfSortedRows.reverse();

for (let row of arrayOfSortedRows)
    document.getElementById('search-results-table').querySelector('tbody').appendChild(row);
```

Provavelmente não é o jeito mais legível e otimizado de fazer essa tarefa, mas no meu nível de Javascript é o que eu consegui pensar.

De qualquer forma, o código do @Ricardo Pontual compartilhou *pareceu* ser o mais rápido dentre os três.

Comment: boa sugestão, eu só mudaria um ponto, antes do `for` final, para ficar mais legível e fazer isso uma vez (está fazendo atualmente dentro do laço for. ou seja, repete para casa linha que existir), eu criaria uma variável `var tbody = document.getElementById('search-results-table').querySelector('tbody')` e no `for` faria simplemente `tbody.appendChild(row);` ;)